# How to convert an expression to linq with nested foreach when the first element is being modified

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble on how to convert this to Linq. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
            foreach (var stat in stats)
            {
                foreach (var record in worked)
                {
                    if (stat.Name != record.Name) continue;
                    stat.WorkedToday = record.RecordCount;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you explain us what you're trying to do? It's unclear how your classes look.

Comment: Thanks for all replies and sorry for the confusion. worked is a List<> of my POCO class. I want to add one value from one List<> of a different POCO class that has the same Name property. Ie. stat.Name = record.Name and I want to assign stat.WorkedToday to the value to recordRecordCount. Both classes are populated by two separated store procedures correctly. Now I want to add the value from one store procedure to the one property of the other class.

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ, any specific reason?

Comment: @AmeyKamat I think LINQ syntax looks more tidy and clear.

Comment: @Juanjo Yes it is looks tidy and clear but performance wise it is slower than the traditional foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find an answer in [.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OVmkrM) I hope this will help

```
//be careful method 'First' can throw an exception if there is no such element in sequence
stats
  .ForEach(s => s.WorkedToday = worked.First(w => w.Name == s.Name).RecordCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Baximilian. Here is his answer that checks for nulls:

```
stats.ForEach(s =>
            {
                var firstOrDefault = worked.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name == s.Name);
                s.WorkedToday = firstOrDefault != null ? firstOrDefault.RecordCount : 0;
            });
```